# React Native select row on ListView when push it

Tags: listview, react-native

when I populate ListView with ten or less elements I can select specific row on touch it and change the row background color. But when I put more of 10 elements in a ListView the application not change fine this.state.data. If i variable in for loop is > 10 can't change his state to false/true and I can´t change the row background color...

Any suggestions?

```
class UbicacionScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      dataSource: ds,
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {

    var datas = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
       datas.push({
          row: i,
          isSelect: false,
       });
    }

    this.setState({data: datas})
    this.setState({
       dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(datas)
    })    
  }

  render() {

    return (      
      <ScrollView style={styles.body}>        
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.listReglamentos}>
              <List style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', marginTop: 14}}>
                <ListView
                  renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}                  
                />
            </List>
          </View>      
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  _renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => { this._onPressRow(rowID, rowData) }}>
          <View style={[rowData.isSelect ? styles.activeRow : styles.deactivedRow, styles.style_row_view]}>
            <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.municipio}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.style_text}>{rowData.isSelect ? 'true' : 'false'}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
  }

  _onPressRow = (rowID, rowData) => {
      rowData.isSelect = !rowData.isSelect;
      var dataClone = this.state.data;
      dataClone[rowID] = rowData;
      this.setState({
        data: dataClone
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `data` array just for comparison. You can save the selected value in state and then change your this line

```
<View style={[
    (rowData.isSelect)
    ? styles.activeRow 
    : styles.deactivedRow
    , styles.style_row_view
]}>
```

to

```
<View style={[
  (this.state.selectedValue == rowData.municipio) 
    ? styles.activeRow 
    : styles.deactivedRow
    , styles.style_row_view
]}>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I modified the code for this:

<View style={[
   (this.state.selectedId == rowID)
   ? styles.activeRow
   : styles.deactiveRow
   , styles.style_row_view
]}>

The solution to my problem is:

<ListView
   initialListSize={this.state.data.length} // ListView work with 10 items by default
   renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
   dataSource={this.state.dataSource}                  
/>

Comment: now are you able to get the proper selected value or not?

Comment: Yes, the main error was not indicate that the ListView had to be initialized with initialListSize with the value of the size of the array. Thanks