# React-native disable and re-able an item on-click in a list view ? (Redux)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, listview, react-native

I have a listview in react-native,i want to disable an item onclick or remove it.Please suggest me a proper way to do it,is there anyway to disable and re-enable an item in listview in react-native(please not that it has to be in redux pattern).And if there is any libraries please suggest me one.

Comment: you can have `isActive` state and condition based on that

Comment: please,give me a link or small example something to refer onto

Comment: not sure code is working or not but you will get idea from this, how to set state and manipulate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813742/react-native-select-row-on-listview-when-push-it/44815120#44815120
Give it try with this, and update your code if any issue arises